# How do I enter into vimdiff mode given two splits are already open?

Tags: vimdiff

I know you would normally enter into vimdiff mode from the terminal with
`vimdiff file1 file2`. However, I frequently find myself already in vim with multiple different splits, and I'd like to run vimdiff on two specific splits, and then turn vimdiff off.

How would I go about this?

N.B. there might be other splits in my vim session that I don't want to be comparing. So I might have 4 vertical splits and I want to run vimdiff on split 1 with split 3, look at some differences, and then turn the diff off.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The command is called `:diffthis`. It must be executed in every window you want to add to the comparison.

The inverse is `:diffoff` which exits diff mode in the current window. To exit diff mode in all applicable windows add a *bang*: `:diffoff!`.

Comment: The `cod` mapping from tpope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) can be handy.

Comment: @mMontu It maps exactly to `diffthis` / `diffoff`. So it's useful if you're already using vim-unimpaired. Otherwise, it's not a problem to create such mapping yourself.

Comment: @Matt glorious - thank you, this works a treat.

Comment: To quickly accomplish this in your splits, you can use :windo  as in ":windo diffthis".

Answer (score 2):

Noting that two `:diffthis` commands ought to be issued with the existing two-split view, here's a quick Autohotkey snippet that does the trick - it simply emulates key-input to the Vim window by issuing `:diffthis` twice.

```
            send :diffthis
            send {enter}
            send ^w
            send w
            send :diffthis
            send {enter}
```

Looking forward to a native Vimscript/Lua-based solution.

---

### Correction: `:windo diffthis` does the trick!

Kudos to  Christian Brabandt.

Note, `:windo diffoff` achieves the same function as `:diffoff!`.

Comment: easier: `:windo :diffthis` if only two splits are opened