# Can vimdiff for git diffs be started in tab of current process?

Tags: vimdiff, git

Let's say I have a file buffer open and a `:terminal` split open in 1 tab page. I'd like to create a new tab where I run `vimdiff` but have my git diff showing. I'm trying to get `git difftool HEAD~1` to show up in my current vim process, just in another tab page.

Is this possible on Vim 8 without plugins?

I kind of get this illusion when I do `:tab terminal` and then run `git difftool HEAD~1`. However, this starts a vim subprocess and I'd like to avoid that.

Kind of like this question: [How do I enter into vimdiff mode given two splits are already open?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/how-do-i-enter-into-vimdiff-mode-given-two-splits-are-already-open) but for git diffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is certainly doable in vanilla `vim`, I suggest you take a look at [tpope's excellent `vim-fugitive` plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). Then, you simply need to do `:tab Gdiff` to get what you want.

If you really don't want to install any plug-ins, the following might work assuming the current file is in buffer no. 1:

1. `:tabnew | r! git show HEAD^:$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)#1:t`
2. In the newly opened tab, `:vert sb 1 | windo diffthis`

### Explanation

1. first opens a new tab with `tabnew` and loads the contents of the `HEAD^` version of the file in buffer 1 into it.
2. opens a vertical split containing buffer 1 with `vert sb 1`, then issues `:diffthis` to all buffers in the tab to enter diff mode.

### Edit

The OP asked for some more explanation on step 1.
`git show` needs an input of the form `<rev>:<path>` where `<path>` has to be relative to the root of the working tree. For example, if the absolute path of the file in buffer 1 is `/a/b/foo.ext` so that `b` contains your `.git` folder (i.e. `b` is the root of your repo), in order for `git show` to work properly you would have to invoke it with `HEAD^:b/foo.e`. Using either `/a/b/foo.ext` or `foo.ext` won't work. So I used `git rev-parse --show-prefix` to obtain the path of the current folder relative to the git root (which would be `b/`) in this example.

Then, I used `vim` path expansion to append the name of the file (that is `foo.ext`). `#1` tells `vim` to fetch the path of whatever file is loaded in buffer 1, and `:t` extracts the "tail", which is everything after the last `/` in the path returned by `#1`. In some cases `#1` and `#1:t` are equal, but this is not always the case. For instance, if you ran `vim b/foo.ext` then `#1` would return `b/foo.ext` instead of just `foo.ext`.
Check out `:help expand` for more info.

Of course, you could just enter the path manually, as in `:tabnew | r! git show HEAD^:b/foo.ext`, and it would work. But the version above is scriptable or you can assign to a map.

Comment: Cool! Could you explain step 1 a little more? I ran `:tabnew | r! git show HEAD^:$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)` and I get a list of files. But when I add `#1` then I get the file contents. Is there a specific section in the manual that talks more about this syntax? (Also, what's `:t` at the end do?)

Comment: I think `:help :%` or `:help :#` will get you there

Comment: @425nesp see the updated answer

Comment: To avoid relying on the buffer-number: `tabedit % | diffthis | vertical new | diffthis | read !git show HEAD^:#:t`